# iPad: how to add a overlay view on master-detail window?

Tags: ios, ipad, master-detail

My application is an iPad master-detail view based. Now I want to implement a feature, but I have no idea how to do, please help.

I want to add a overlay view to show some text. When screen is landscape, I want the text view overlay on the master view in order to not cover any portion of detail view; when screen is portrait, since the master view is hidden, I want the text view to be overlay on bottom side of detail view.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `UISplitViewController`, it has a property called `viewControllers`.  This property is an array containing two UIViewControllers: the first one is your master view and the second one is the detail view.  You can set up your overlays on top of these views, and swap the overlay from one view to the other in the rotation methods.